# Autofoco em EditText não funciona

Tags: java, android

Tenho um `EditText` que sempre precisa estar em foco, e um `Button` qualquer:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtCod"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number" />
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLimpar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="limpar"
        android:text="Limpar" />
```

Quando executo o método, ele não respeita o `requestfocus()` e "pula" para o botão.

Método:

```
public void confere(View view) {

     String codigo = cod.getText().toString();
     try {
         salvar(codigo);
         cod.setText("");
         cod.requestFocus();
     } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

---

Setando no `onCreate`:

`this.limpar.setFocusable(false);`

Dessa forma ele funciona. Mas se eu tenho vários elementos (`Button`, `Layout`, etc), preciso ficar setando o `setFocusable(false)`, e as vezes mesmo setando tudo, não funciona.

Teria como usar somente o `requestfocus()` no `EditText`, sem ter que ficar setando outras coisas ?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode colocar no `edittext` o campo que vai receber o próximo foco, assim:

```
android:nextFocusDown="@id/seuEdittext"
```

Se o seu foco estiver setado para o de cima, faz assim:

```
android:nextFocusUP="@id/seuEdittext"
```